# NoClassDefFoundError when attempting to use openCV in java while running NixOS

Tags: java, maven, opencv, nixos

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on the use of openCV in java while also learning how to use NixOS.

I have the following flake:

```
    {
      inputs = {
        nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };
  outputs = {
    nixpkgs,
    flake-utils,
    ...
  }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system: let
      javaVersion = 19;

      overlays = [
        (self: super: rec {
          jdk = super."jdk${toString javaVersion}";
          maven = super.maven.override {
            inherit jdk;
          };
        })
      ];
      pkgs = import nixpkgs {inherit overlays system;};
    in {
      devShell = let
        generateEditorConfig = pkgs.writeShellScriptBin "generateEditorConfig" ''
          if [ ! -f .editorconfig ]; then
            echo "root = true" > .editorconfig
            echo "" >> .editorconfig
            echo "[*]" >> .editorconfig
            echo "end_of_line = lf" >> .editorconfig
            echo "insert_final_newline = true" >> .editorconfig
            echo "indent_style = tab" >> .editorconfig
            echo "tab_width = 4" >> .editorconfig
            echo "charset = utf-8" >> .editorconfig
            echo "" >> .editorconfig
            echo "[*.{yaml,yml}]" >> .editorconfig
            echo "indent_style = space" >> .editorconfig
            echo "indent_size = 2" >> .editorconfig
            echo "" >> .editorconfig
            echo "[*.{md,nix}]" >> .editorconfig
            echo "indent_style = space" >> .editorconfig
            echo "indent_size = 2" >> .editorconfig
          fi
        '';
      in
        pkgs.mkShell {
          name = "java";
          buildInputs = with pkgs; [
            jdk
            maven
            tomcat9
            opencv
          ];
          shellHook = ''
            export JAVA_HOME=${pkgs.jdk}
            ${generateEditorConfig}/bin/generateEditorConfig
          '';
        };
    });
}
```

Java file: src/main/java/NerfThis.java

```
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.objdetect.Objdetect;

import nu.pattern.OpenCV;

public class NerfThis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        OpenCV.loadShared();
        
        String sourceImagePath = "src/main/resources/face.jpeg";
        String targetImagePath = "src/main/resources/result.jpeg";
        

        Mat loadedImage = loadImage(sourceImagePath);
        int minFaceSize = Math.round(loadedImage.rows() * 0.1f); 
        MatOfRect facesDetected = new MatOfRect();
        CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier();
        cascadeClassifier.load("./src/main/resources/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(loadedImage, 
            facesDetected, 
            1.1, 
            3, 
          Objdetect.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, 
          new Size(minFaceSize, minFaceSize), 
          new Size() 
        );
        
        Rect[] facesArray = facesDetected.toArray(); 
        for(Rect face : facesArray) { 
            Imgproc.rectangle(loadedImage, face.tl(), face.br(), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3); 
        } 
        saveImage(loadedImage, targetImagePath);

    }

    public static Mat loadImage(String imagePath) {
        Imgcodecs imageCodecs = new Imgcodecs();
        return imageCodecs.imread(imagePath);
    }

    public static void saveImage(Mat imageMatrix, String targetPath) {
        Imgcodecs imgcodecs = new Imgcodecs();
        imgcodecs.imwrite(targetPath, imageMatrix);
    }
}
```

And my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sigubrat-nerfThis</groupId>
  <artifactId>NerfThis</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>NerfThis</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0-0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <mainClass>NerfThis</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>

         </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I can build it just fine using Maven, but when I try to run the jar I get the following error:

```
java -jar target/NerfThis-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: Unable to initialize main class NerfThis
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Mat
```

I've been debugging this for hours now and can't understand why it's struggling to find the Definition for Mat.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: my shade-plugin wasn't running since it was in the pluginManagement section. Moved it out and removed the pluginManagement entirely which solved it.